# WordPress Owl Carousel add Image issue - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm trying to get further, new Image Links that are loaded to display.

Currently 5 are displayed, but we want to add a sixth & maybe 2 or 3 others in the future.

The issue we are having is when we add the sixth, it overwrites one of the existing 5.

Can anyone help with, what I suspect is the Function, to allow us to add more?

Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="content">
<div class="visible-xs visible-sm" style="background: #367586;color: white;width: 100%;">
    <h2 style="color: white;padding: 20px;text-align: center;">Call us on <a style="text-decoration: none;color: white;" href="tel:0141999999">0131 344 4146</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="pageTitle">
    <h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
</div>

<?php
    $posts =  get_posts('category='.$cat);
    vvwc_carouselList($posts);
?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

PHP

```
function vvwc_carouselList($posts, $postId=null){
if(!empty($posts)){
    echo '
        <div class="nonCarousel">
            <ul class="list-inline">
    ';
        $x = 1;
        foreach($posts as $post){
            $active = '';
            $feature = '';
            if($postId == $post->ID){
                $active = 'active';
                $feature = 'feature';
            }
            if($x == 5 || $x == 1){
                ?>
                <div class='row'>
                <?php
            }
            echo '
                <li class="col-md-3 '.$feature.'">
                    <div class="'.$active.' carousel-border">
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                        <a  data-item="'.$post->ID.'" href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">
                ';
                            if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
                            }
                            echo "<div class='camperTitle'>" . strtoupper($post->post_title) . "</div>";
                echo '
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            ';

            if($x == 4 || $x == count($posts)+1 ){
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            $x ++;
        }
    echo '
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    ';
}
echo '
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $(".carousel ul").owlCarousel({
                items: 4,
                pagination: false,
                navigation: true,
                navigationText: false,
                slideSpeed: 1000,
                rewindSpeed: 1000
            });
        });
    </script>
';
```

}

Comment: try setting `items` to 6

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I replaced:

`$posts =  get_posts('category='.$cat);`

with

`$posts =  get_posts(array(
            'category' =>15,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'posts_per_page'=> 10,
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ));`